# Mouse over effects happening simultaneously in all elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

If the mouse pointer over a div that I want to change the style of two anchor tags under the div and div bg color too. So I just made through jQuery, now that is working fine. But when I added the same div as a duplication then I have another problem, mouse over the effects occurs at a time when the other elements too, becouse the class name is the same, I know that is the reason by haapening like that. I have to keep that class name must be the same. so please teach me how I can fix this, but jQuery.

Please see the following jQuery i used, and you can also see the demo too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".custombox").bind({
                mouseover: function () {

                    $(".custombox").addClass("custombox' + num++ + '");
                    $(".custombox a").css("color", "#fff");
                    $(".deletebtn").css("background-position", "bottom");
                },
                mouseout: function () {
                    $(".custombox a").css("color", "#333");
                    $(".deletebtn").css("background-position", "top");
                }
            });

            $(window).load(function () {
                var coordinates = function (element) {
                    element = $(element);
                    var top = element.position().top;
                    var left = element.position().left;
                    $('#results').text('X: ' + left + ' ' + '   Y: ' + top);
                }

                $('#custombox').draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false,
                    start: function () {
                        coordinates('#custombox');
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        coordinates('#custombox');
                    }

                });

                $('#custombox2').draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false,
                    start: function () {
                        coordinates('#custombox2');
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        coordinates('#custombox2');
                    }

                });
                $("#custombox2").resizable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false, maxHeight: 250, maxWidth: 350, minHeight: 50, minWidth: 50 });

            }); //]]>  

        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vahidrockv/rhY8J/4/)

Thanks
Vahid

Comment: You don't need to have $(window).load() inside $(document).ready() To solve your problem I would look at using the 'this' keyword inside the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mouseover and mouseout handlers you need to target the relevant `coustombox` element. Inside the event handlers `this` refers to the current element, so change you script to

```
$(".custombox").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("custombox' + num++ + '");
    $(this).find("a").css("color", "#fff");
    $(this).find(".deletebtn").css("background-position", "bottom");
}, function () {
    $(this).find("a").css("color", "#333");
    $(this).find(".deletebtn").css("background-position", "top");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ukVQb/)

Comment: Thank you Arun P Johny for giving a Great Answer..!